# Part of the word is an outdated person

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> My prefix is the action of doing an action in the past 
>    My suffix is one in a hundred  
>    If you take a part of my prefix and put it together with my infix and suffix, 
>    I almost got a 'P'ed on diaper. 
>    Turn two letters of the word upside-down, 
>    and part of the word would be an outdated person

What word am I?

Comment: The 3rd line mentions an infix, which is not mentioned in the lines before. Was that deliberately?

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen Yes it was supposed to give more clues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> [didapper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/didapper#English) ?

Prefix:

> **did** - the action of doing an action in the past

Suffix:

> **per**, as in percent - one in a hundred

If you take a part of my prefix and put it together with the infix and suffix, you get

> diaper, with a 'P' to spare

An outdated person is a...

> **dabber**, if the Ps are made Bs by flipping them upside-down.  To be frank, I thought [dabbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dab_(dance)) was still popular.  [What does that say about me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LV0wTtiJygY)?

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Congrats, that is the correct answer!